# Openstack HEAT : Adding new instances manually to existing stack via HEAT template

Tags: openstack, scaling, heat

I have created an openstack stack via HEAT template using the `openstack stack create` command. If I want to add new instances to this same stack via HEAT template manually, whats the ideal approach?

I know that `openstack stack update` command exists, but it is more to update the resources in the current stack, rather than adding extra instances, right? Or stack update is the only way to scale up ?

Answer (score 2):

> I know that openstack stack update command exists, but it is more to update the resources in the current stack, rather than adding extra instances, right? Or stack update is the only way to scale up ?

Scaling out your stack depends on what your template looks like and how you expose the instance count through a stack parameter and which resource type you are using. Below is an example of how you could do it with OS::Heat::ResourceGroup, but if you are using an ASG or Senlin resource within the stack, the method may be different (for example you could just hit the Senlin API directly to scale)

```
parameters:
  node_count:
    type: number
    default: 2
    description: number of nodes
resources:
  my_group:
    type::OS::Heat::ResourceGroup
    properties:
      count: {get_param: node_count}
      resource_def:
        type: OS::Nova::Server
        properties:
          name: my-instance-%index%
          flavor: my-flavor
          image: my-image
          networks:
            --network: my-network
```

Creating a stack with those resources and parameters would let you do something like:

```
openstack stack update --existing --parameter node_count=3 my-stack
```

--existing will use the existing template (allowing for an update without needing to provide the template again)
--parameter targets one of the stack's exposed parameters, in this case, node_count

This will use the properties of the resource group that has the parameter that is being updated to build out a new node, identical to other nodes built by the ResourceGroup

Hope that helps!

edit: added the correct type (OS::Nova::Server) to the resource_def